# Chamar uma tela nova usando um botão (Scene Builder, JavaFX)

Tags: java, javafx, fxml, scenebuilder

Criei duas telas, uma principal e outra que eu pretendo chamar usando um botão, como seria o método adequado para chamar essa tela secundária?

Answer (score 0):

```
findViewById(R.id.botao).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent variavel = new Intent(context, classeSegundaTela.class);
                startActivity(variavel);
            }
        });
```